# System invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I'm having a problem with C# and sql connection. when it comes to C# I'm a noobie and have pretty much no idea what I'm doing :/ I am trying to follow a tutorial which explaines how to do everything step by step and for some reason it doesn't work when I try to do it on my database and application.

This is my Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Praca_Inzynierska
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Connection sqlCon = new Connection();
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'restaurantDataSet2.Employees' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.restaurantDataSet2.Employees);

         FillTextFieldsEmployees(1);

    }
    public void FillTextFieldsEmployees(int EmployeeID)
    {
        list = sqlCon.GetAllEmployees(EmployeeID);

        textFirstName.Text = list[0].ToString();
        textLastName.Text = list[1].ToString();
        textAdress.Text = list[2].ToString();
        textCity.Text = list[3].ToString();
        textPhoneNumber.Text = list[4].ToString();
        textEmail.Text = list[5].ToString();
        textBirthDate.Text = list[6].ToString();
        textAge.Text = list[7].ToString();
        textGender.Text = list[8].ToString();
        textTitle.Text = list[9].ToString();
        textSalary.Text = list[10].ToString();
    }

    private void dataGridViewEmployees_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = dataGridViewEmployees.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        int currentIndex = (int) dataGridViewEmployees.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        FillTextFieldsEmployees(currentIndex);
    }
}
}
```

This is my class `Connection`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Praca_Inzynierska
{
  public class Connection
  {
   private String connectionString = "Data Source = MAKSKOMP\\SQL2012EXP; Initial      Catalog = Restaurant;Integrated Security = True";

   public ArrayList GetAllEmployees(int EmployeeID)
   {
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           String query = "SELECT *  FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = '" + EmployeeID +"'";
           using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
           {
               var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
               var list = new ArrayList();
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   String FirstName = reader.GetString(1);
                   String LastName = reader.GetString(2);
                   String Adress = reader.GetString(3);
                   String City = reader.GetString(4);
                   String PhoneNumber = reader.GetString(5);
                   String Email = reader.GetString(6);
                   DateTime BirthDate = reader.GetDateTime(7);
                   Int16 Age = reader.GetInt16(8);
                   String Gender = reader.GetString(9);
                   String Title = reader.GetString(10);
                   int Salary = reader.GetInt32(11);

                   list.Add(FirstName);
                   list.Add(LastName);
                   list.Add(Adress);
                   list.Add(City);
                   list.Add(PhoneNumber);
                   list.Add(Email);
                   list.Add(BirthDate);
                   list.Add(Age);
                   list.Add(Gender);
                   list.Add(Title);
                   list.Add(Salary);

               }
               connection.Close();
               reader.Close();
               return list;
           }

       }
   }
}
```

}

and for some reason it breaks in this particular place

```
  int currentIndex = (int) dataGridViewEmployees.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
```

I have tried to debug it step by step and also it doesn't finish this loop

```
 while (reader.Read())
           {
               String FirstName = reader.GetString(1);
               String LastName = reader.GetString(2);
               String Adress = reader.GetString(3);
               String City = reader.GetString(4);
               String PhoneNumber = reader.GetString(5);
               String Email = reader.GetString(6);
               DateTime BirthDate = reader.GetDateTime(7);
               Int16 Age = reader.GetInt16(8);
               String Gender = reader.GetString(9);
               String Title = reader.GetString(10);
               int Salary = reader.GetInt32(11);

               list.Add(FirstName);
               list.Add(LastName);
               list.Add(Adress);
               list.Add(City);
               list.Add(PhoneNumber);
               list.Add(Email);
               list.Add(BirthDate);
               list.Add(Age);
               list.Add(Gender);
               list.Add(Title);
               list.Add(Salary);

           }
```

it ends on

```
Int16 Age = reader.GetInt16(8);
```

Comment: Problem is actually what it says. You're trying to read a "short" (Int16) but it's not. In debug just do GetObject(8) in QuickWatch window and you'll see its real type.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a strongly typed entity for your employee (e.g. `List<Employee>` and not `ArrayList`) instead of referencing the values by index (this allows access via more maintainable code `int Employee.Age` vs `list[7].ToString()`)

Comment: Don't know where to start with this. You need to get a .net book that covers databases with C#. You are making a world of hurt for your self or the next developer. Ask yourself what happens if you reorder or take out one column from that table for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code already uses a Data Bound grid, try binding the TextBox controls to the same binding source as well. It doesn't make much sense to fetch the data from the database when the data is already loaded into the grid...